# How to implement function composition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, function-composition

Below are three functions that need to be composed and give us the output `30`:

```js
const add = (a) => a + 10;
const mul = (a) => a * 10;
const divide = (a) => a / 5; 

// How to implement `compositionFunction`?
compositionFunction(add, mul, divide)(5);
//=> 30
```

Expected output is `30` because:

```
5 + 10 = 15
15 * 10 = 150
150 / 5 = 30
```

Comment: create a `function` or another `const` with all three operation ?

Comment: None of your functions return anything. You should read about arrow function syntax.

Comment: What the OP refers to as `customComposeFn` actually is a `pipe` approach.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes, often called "pipe". Compose *often* goes in the opposite direction. Reasoning being `f(g(x)) = compose(f, g)(x)`.

Comment: ... which meanwhile got provided by *R4ncid*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework question.

Comment: 150 / 3 is not 30

Comment: Although the question does not show an attempt to solve the problem, the question itself is well defined and has interesting solutions that could be useful to others.  I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```js
const add = (a) =>  a + 10 ;
const mul = (a) =>  a * 10 ;
const divide = (a) => a / 5 ; 
// How to use this function -----

const customComposeFn = (...f) => v => f.reduce((res, f) => f(res), v)

console.log(customComposeFn(add, mul, divide)(5));
```

Comment: `compose` is colloquially know as right-to-left function composition. What you've done is `pipe` IMHO.

Comment: @customcommander to be fair, that's what OP asked for. I clarified the title of the question. I do agree with you, though - compose is most often right-to-left.

Comment: With just recursion it could be  `const compose = (f, ...rest) => f ? x => compose(...rest)(f(x)) : x => x;` but I like that you used `.reduce` much better!

Answer (score 1):

There are two flavours of function composition:

1. *left-to-right* function composition *aka* `pipe`
2. *right-to-left* function composition *aka* `compose`

Here's a recursive implementation just for fun:
*<sup>This assumes that there are at least two functions to compose</sup>*

```js
const compose = (...fn) => {
  const [[f, g], x] = [fn.slice(-2), fn.slice(0, -2)];
  const h = a => f(g(a));
  return x.length ? compose(...x, h) : h;
}

const pipe = (...fn) => {
  const [f, g, ...x] = fn;
  const h = a => g(f(a));
  return x.length ? pipe(h, ...x) : h;
}
```

Let's try:

```js
const foo = x => x + 'foo';
const bar = x => x + 'bar';
const baz = x => x + 'baz';

pipe(foo, bar, baz)('');
//=> 'foobarbaz'

compose(foo, bar, baz)('');
//=> 'bazbarfoo'
```

Comment: You can peel off an argument rather than slicing like this:  `const compose = (f, ...rest) => f ? x => compose(...rest)(f(x)) : x => x;`, which returns an identity function in the terminal case.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const add = (a) => a + 10;
const mul = (a) => a * 10;
const divide = (a) => a / 5;
const customComposeFn = (...fn) => {
    return function (arg) {
        if (fn.length > 0) {
            const output = fn[0](arg);
            return customComposeFn(...fn.splice(1))(output);
        } else {
            return arg;
        }
    };
};
const res = customComposeFn(add, mul, divide)(5);
console.log(`res`, res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I would do:

```js
function customComposeFn(...funcs) {
  return function(arg) {
    let f, res = arg;
    while (f = funcs.shift()) {
      res = f(res)
    }
    return res;
  }
}

const add = a => a + 10;
const mul = a => a * 10;
const divide = a => a / 5;
// How to use this function -----
console.log(customComposeFn(add, mul, divide)(5));
```